# BLE device randomly disconnecting

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using a BLE device and connecting it to an via using swift. When I turn it on it'll connect, disconnect, then reconnect. I have no idea why it's disconnecting in the first place, battery is at 100% and I have nothing that triggers a disconnect, anybody have an idea of what could be happening? here's a few of my functions for reference

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        kestrelPeripheral = peripheral
        kestrelPeripheral.delegate = self
        manager.connect(kestrelPeripheral)
        manager.stopScan()
        self.kestrelIsConnected = true

    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {

        delegate?.didDisconnect()
        cancelReading()
        self.kestrelIsConnected = false
        self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.isInitialReading = false
        kestrelPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        delegate?.didConnect()
    }
```

for more context:

```
func startReading() {
        self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        self.takeReading = true
        progressHUD = ReadingProgressHUD(text: "Taking Reading")
        self.vc!.view.addSubview(self.progressHUD)
    }
```

This would start the reading of values

Comment: Are you in an environment with a large number of wireless devices? From experience, we had a lot of issues keeping stable connections with ~100 similar devices all chatting at the same time.

Comment: There are alot of devices in the area, but the code only searches for the specific CBUUID

Comment: I understand, and had the same setup at work. The issue we had was that all of the interference from the different BT devices made for a "noisy" environment where maintaining a good connection was challenging. Granted, these were bottom dollar BT chips so YMMV...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I agree with CodeBender that having a lot of devices in the area can be challenging, but several things about your code make me suspicious.

First, you're not logging anything, so it's hard to know exactly what's going on. You definitely want to log each step.

Make sure you're scanning for exactly the service you want; do not pass `nil` in `scanForPeripherals`. Similarly, do not pass `nil` to `discoverServices`.

But the most suspicious piece is here, and I'm suspecting it might be the cause:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
    ...
    self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    ...
}
```

You shouldn't be creating a new manager every time any peripheral disconnects. A central manager handles all the peripherals; not just one connection. You should be setting `manager` one time for the entire run of the program, and you should generally avoid having multiple `CBCentralManager` objects in the system. It's not impossible to make multiple managers work, but I've found they often get in each others' way a bit.

My suspicion is that you're connecting to more devices than you think you are, and when you disconnect from one of them, you reset your manager and disrupt the others. It may not be that, it could be a lot of things, but that's the most suspicious part of the code you've posted here.

Comment: How can I research for the device after it disconnects?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If it starts advertising again, then you can search for it with `scanForPeripherals()`, but if you already know the identifier, you can just reconnect to the peripheral directly (using `retrievePeripheral()` to get a CBPeripheral if you need it, and then `connect()`)

Comment: to my knowledge, the ```self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)``` will start the search for the device I'm looking for, once it disconnects it is no longer scanning for that device. I'm wondering how I can start scanning for that device again once it disconnects

Comment: That's not correct. That line of code creates a new `CBCentralManager`, which you generally want to do exactly one time. You scan search for devices by calling `scanForPeripherals()` and you connect to them by calling `connect()`. Creating a central manager doesn't do either of those things by itself.

Comment: That's weird, i've haven't been calling ```scanForPeripherals()``` anywhere, only ```self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)``` and it'll connect, I'm going to post some more code for context, would you mind looking it at real quick?

Comment: Correction: I call ```scanForPeripherals()``` in ```.poweredOn``` case in ```centralManagerDidUpdateState```

Comment: Right; if you didn't call `scanForPeripherals()`, you'd never see the call to `didDiscover:`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1 for the walk-through.

Comment: Also see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice/BestPracticesForInteractingWithARemotePeripheralDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH6-SW1 for a lot of very useful info.